# When RadioButton Clicked, I Want To Display Values From Model In View

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to display a query from my model based on a selected radio button.

My Code for View is:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblQuestionType" runat="server" Text="Question Type"></asp:Label>    
<ul>
    <li><%=Html.RadioButton("QuestionType", "1", true) %> Multiple - Choice</li>
    <li><%=Html.RadioButton("QuestionType", "2", false) %> Short Answer</li>
    <li><%=Html.RadioButton("QuestionType", "3", false) %> Participant List</li>
 </ul>
```

And the value of 1 , 2 or 3 is pass to my model that contains the following :

```
public string[][] GetQuestionTypes(int questionGroup)
{
    string[][] resultArray; // message shown to user
    OleDbDataReader MyOleDbDataReader = DBConn("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QUESTION_TYPES WHERE Groupings = " + questionGroup);
    MyOleDbDataReader.Read();
    int size = Convert.ToInt32(MyOleDbDataReader.GetValue(0));
    resultArray = new string[size][];
    MyOleDbDataReader.Close();
    MyOleDbConnection.Close();
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        resultArray[x] = new string[3];
    }

    MyOleDbDataReader = DBConn("SELECT QType_ID, Text, Description FROM QUESTION_TYPES WHERE Groupings = " + questionGroup);

    if (MyOleDbDataReader.HasRows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            MyOleDbDataReader.Read();
            resultArray[i][0] = Convert.ToString(MyOleDbDataReader["QType_ID"]);
            resultArray[i][1] = Convert.ToString(MyOleDbDataReader["Text"]);
            resultArray[i][2] = Convert.ToString(MyOleDbDataReader["Description"]);
        }
    }    
    MyOleDbDataReader.Close();
    MyOleDbConnection.Close();
    return resultArray;
}
```

How would I in javascript be able to display the array returned as a DropDownList from the GetQuestionTypes method?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript to get values from my model to change my ViewData on my view on a radiobutton change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137990/javascript-to-get-values-from-my-model-to-change-my-viewdata-on-my-view-on-a-radi). No need to ask the same question every hour or so.

Comment: thanks for noticing, I was afraid my title scared people =/

Comment: you can edit your original question if you don't like the title. As far as this duplicate is concerned you should delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Is this something that you could do on the same page? If it is, look at making an asychronous call when the radio button is changed using jQuery's .getJSON.  You could build the HTML for your drop down list inside of the method that your .getJSON will call.